# Is this a weed, please help me identify this plant

Tags: identification

Found in backyard in Sydney, Australia. Can someone please identify this plant. At first I thought it was a kind of hosta.[image]

Comment: My first reaction is that it looked hosta like as well based strictly on the leaves but I don't think that's what it is.

Comment: It kind of reminds me of alstroemeria, but really hard to tell from this photo.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you very much Debbie M, for the direction.

I now think it is Alstroemeria psittacina after some image searching.